# Same Network Cilent IP Match

Tags: php, ip

I did a simple website where the votes is identified with the visitor IP. So the person have one vote.

The problem is... if two devices is on the same network, both of them is counted as one...

how to solve this problem.

Comment: They may be going through a router or firewall that does NAT, so all users on the network have the same public IP. This is why it's not a good idea to use IP to identify users. Sometimes multiple users have the same IP, and ISPs can also reassign an IP to different users at different times.

Comment: @Barmar any suggestions?

Comment: The best way is to require a login. If that's not feasible, use a cookie.